# Spring integration DSL creating Sftp Inbound Adapter in java 1.7

Tags: spring-integration

I am creating a sftp inbound flow in spring dsl but when I am trying to test this in junit the mesage is coming null. I think the sftp ibound adapter is not starting properly, but not sure. So I am not able to go further. Can any ony one please provide any pointer to it as I am not able to proceed.

This is my flow....

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory)
                        .preserveTimestamp(true).remoteDirectory(remDir)
                        .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")
                        .localFilenameExpression("#this.toUpperCase()")
                        .localDirectory(new File(localDir))
                        .remoteFileSeparator("/"),
                        new Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(
                                    SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec e) {
                                e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
                                        .autoStartup(true)
                                        .poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000)
                                                .maxMessagesPerPoll(1));
                            }
                        })
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue("sftpInboundResultChannel"))
                .get();
    }
```

This is my session Factory...

```
        @Autowired
        private DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory;

        @Bean
        public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory() {
            DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(
                    true);
            factory.setHost("111.11.12.143");
            factory.setPort(22);
            factory.setUser("sftp");
            factory.setPassword("*******");         
            return factory;
        }
```

This is my Pollable channel..

```
    @Autowired
        private PollableChannel sftpInboundResultChannel;   

    @Bean
        public PollableChannel sftpChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }
```

And this is my Test method..

```
    @Test
    public void testSftpInboundFlow() {

        Message<?> message = ((PollableChannel) sftpInboundResultChannel).receive(1000);     //Not receiving any message
        System.out.println("message====" + message);
        Object payload = message.getPayload();

        File file = (File) payload;
        message = this.sftpInboundResultChannel.receive(1000);
        file = (File) message.getPayload(); 

    }
```

Comment: Turn on debug logging and look for the endpoint start log messages and polling activity. If you see none, post the complete startup log (debug for all of `org.springframework`). It's probably too big for here so use pastebin or a github gist or similar.

Comment: Do you have `@EnableIntegration` on your `@Configuration` class ?

Comment: How about to increase the 'receiveTimeout' in your test, because it is the same right now like the 'fixedRate'? So, not enough time to wait for something in the channel

Comment: HI Artem,   I have Added @EnableIntegration and increase the 'receiveTimeout'  , now my code is working. Thanks a lot for your valuable comment.

Comment: HI Artem,  I found that when my local directory is empty then all files from remote directory are successfully copied to my local directory but if some files are present in the local directory then none of the files getting copied from the remote directory. So can you please advice me on this.

Comment: HI Artem, Could please provide any work around for this issues ...